# access 2007 where condition in Buttons linking between two forms

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

For a simple borrowed item database, I am trying to link two forms together via a button 'Return'

However, the button does not apply a filter to the correct Item.

In the main menu their is a subform that shows the list of borrowed item via a Query. The list of borrowed Items is a continuous form with the button 'return'

The following event is used when the button is clicked:

```
OpenForm
form nameReturn
View Form
Data mode Edit
window mode Normal

searchforrecord
object type form
object name return
record First
Where condition = ="[Item_ID]="&[Item_ID]
```

In that situation access does not apply a filter, after some tutorials I discovered another methode and tested it.

```
OpenForm
form nameReturn
View Form
Where condition = ="[Item_ID]="&[Item_ID]
Data mode Edit
window mode Normal
```

in that situation a filter is applied but it does not find any records. Could anyone help in what i did wrong to find link the two forms that use the same table?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What kind of data is your `Item_ID` field?

Comment: The Item_ID is a calculated double where the expression is: 3001000+[Id]